# Arcpy Geocoding Script Fails (vague messaging)

Tags: arcpy, python, geocoding

Using ArcMap 10.6 to load a Python script that will geocode 25,000 addresses. It looks like it fail during the actual gecoding attempt with an error:
ERROR 000010: Geocode addresses failed.Failed to execute (GeocodeAddresses).
I've tried switching forward slashes to back slashes, removing spaces in my file directories, and tried using a DBF outside of the GDB or tried using the table as a GDB table.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Data_Projects/OCHIN_CVS/Scripting/OCHIN_Scripting.gdb" 

# GEOCODE OCHIN RECORDS
address_table   = r"C:/Data_Projects/OCHIN_CVS/Scripting/OCHIN_Geocoding.dbf"
address_locator = "C:/StreetMapPremium/Locators/USA_ZIP4_LocalComposite"
address_fields = "Provider_Prefer_Add_Street Address;Provider_Prefer_Add_City City;Provider_Prefer_Add_State State;Provider_Prefer_Add_Zip Zip"

geocode_result  = "C:/Data_Projects/OCHIN_CVS/Scripting/OCHIN_Scripting.gdb/geocode_result"

arcpy.GeocodeAddresses_geocoding(address_table, address_locator, address_fields, geocode_result, "STATIC")   

# DELETE LOCAL VARIABLES
del mxd, df, code

print "Success!"
```

EDIT: I have run this script on a machine that has a Basic license, and on another machine that has an Advanced license. Can anyone shed light on why this might fail?

Comment: A Google on "ERROR 000010 arcgis" returned [this document](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013875) as the first response. It seems to offer a number of options that you didn't list, and has links to other documents as well.

Comment: What is your license level for ArcGIS?

Comment: My license level is Basic. I conduct geocoding routinely using the right click --> geocode addresses method, so I should be able to run it from Python?

Comment: As you're using Static, a basic license is enough. This should not be a license issue.

Comment: What could be the problem then? Has anyone here confirmed that they can run geocoding from python?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by running the Geocode Addresses GP tool and then exporting the model as a Python script. The path to the locator file needs double backslashes as such:

```
USA_ZIP4_LocalComposite = "C:\\StreetMapPremium\\Locators\\USA_ZIP4_LocalComposite"
```

I also added double backslashes for all paths in the geocoding step and it ran successfully. With other processes (like the spatial join, the double back slashes are not needed); seems exclusive to geocoding.

Comment: Your use of forward slash (`/`) should have been fine. I cant explain why it's not. but glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. After much experimenting, it turned out it was because the address table being geocoded, which was on an SQL Server, had a GEOMETRY field I had called SHAPE. I dropped that field and it worked perfectly.

once i had it working, i didnt care enough to examine all the possibilities before moving on. bc of my circumstances, the possibilities were that:

- the input table had a field called SHAPE
- the SHAPE field was of SQL GEOMETRY type
- the SHAPE field was NULL for many features
  (this latter was what ultimately pointed me to the real problem.  i was testing to see if the problem was the input table format, and while exporting to .shp got an error about Null geometry)